# How to make for loop run faster?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

Here is my for loop. It takes very long to run over 100,000 iterations.

```
for urlt in xrange(0, len(clean_url_data)):
    website_title.append(urlt)
    website_title[urlt]=g.extract(clean_url_data[urlt]).title
    print urlt
```

Comment: I suppose `g.extract` is what actually takes time, no?! What does it do...?

Comment: it seems each iteration is independent, so try to use multiprocessing

Comment: Make it faster by serializing/caching your result so you don't have to recalculate it every time you run the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than extending the `website_title` list using `website_title.append(urlt)` and then immediately overwriting that `urlt` item with your title data, you should just append the title data directly to the list.

Also, it's better to iterate directly over the `clean_url_data` list, rather than using an integer loop to index `clean_url_data`. If you need an index you can use `enumerate`. like this:

```
website_title = []
for i, url in enumerate(clean_url_data):
    website_title.append(g.extract(url).title)
    print i
```

If you don't really need that index, you can make things simpler. Here's an approach using a list comprehension, which is a little faster than using append in a loop.

```
website_title = [g.extract(url).title for url in clean_url_data]
```

The list comprehension uses a special LIST_APPEND bytecode, which is basically an operator, so it's faster than looking up the list's `.append` method then calling it; calling a Python function is relatively slow compared to executing an operator.

Comment: `.append` is a function reference that is reevaluated each time through the loop. The bytecode is a good idea, but it's simpler to add `append = website_title.append` before the loop, then replace the `website_title.append(g.extract(url).title)` in the loop by `append(g.extract(url).title)`. This is a lot faster, as it will not be re-evaluated each time in the loop. This was taken from [the official Python performance tips](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips).

Comment: @DavidG. Sure, caching the `.append` method in a local is certainly faster than performing the lookup on each loop iteration. However, it's still not as fast as using a list comprehension. Last time I tested this, the version with cached append was roughly intermediate in speed between the list comp and the non-cached version, but actual speeds vary depending on the Python version.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending a numeric item to list `website_title` and then you overwrite the value of the same item in the list. I don't see how that is useful. If you avoid doing that, your for loop will be a little faster.

As this test shows:

```
# Your version, with append() and assignment
%%timeit
l = []
for n in xrange(100000):
    l.append(n)
    l[n] = 'something'
```

10 loops, best of 3: **22.4 ms per loop**

```
# Without reassignment
%%timeit
l = []
for n in xrange(100000):
    l.append('something')
```

100 loops, best of 3: **16.6 ms per loop**

```
# even better with list comprehension
%%timeit
l = ['something' for n in xrange(100000)]
```

100 loops, best of 3: **7.86 ms per loop**

Answer (score 0):

Please try to compare **range()**, **xrange()**, **map()**. `g.extract` may cost your time.

```
def set_website_title(urlt):
    if urlt not in website_title:
        website_title.append(urlt)
        website_title[urlt] = g.extract(clean_url_data[urlt]).title
        print urlt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    map(set_website_title, clean_url_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

As galaxyan mentioned, you can use multiprocessing to do that. Here is an example snippet:

```
def clean(url):
    return {'url': url, 'title': g.extract(url).title}

from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool()
website_info = pool.map(clean, clean_url_data)
```